# Is any rebirths of humans mentioned in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, identification-request, rebirth

I know Devas and Asuras' reincarnations is mentioned in Mahabharata? But, Is any human being's reincarnation mentioned in the Mahabharata or it's appendix Harivamsha?

Comment: your two questions are unrelated - it would be better to split them up.

Comment: @SK i separated them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Krishna and Arjuna were the incarnations of the sages Narayana and Nara respectively who themselves were the incarnations of Lord Vishnu. As discussed [in this answer of mine](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53651/20968).

Though Shantanu was the reincarnation of the King Mahabhisha as discussed in the above answer. He was also the incarnation of Lord Vishnu as discussed [in this answer of mine](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53588/20968).

Shikhandi was the rebirth of Amba. Plus, she was also called the rebirth of a Rakshasa.

> "Duryodhana said, 'Tell me, O grandsire, how Sikhandin, O Ganga's son, having before been born a daughter, afterwards became a man, O foremost of warriors.' "Bhishma said, 'O great king, the eldest and beloved queen of king Drupada was, O monarch, childless (at first). During those years, king Drupada, O monarch, paid his adoration to the god Sankara for the sake of offspring, resolving in his mind to compass my destruction and practising the austerest of penances. And he begged Mahadeva, saying, 'Let a son, and not a daughter, be born unto me. I desire, O god, a son for revenging myself upon Bhishma.' Thereupon, that god of gods said unto him, 'Thou shalt have a child who will be a female and male. Desist, O king, it will not be otherwise.' Returning then to his capital, he addressed his wife, saying, 'O great goddess, great hath been the exertion made by me. Undergoing ascetic austerities, I paid my adorations to Siva, and I was told by Sambhu that my child becoming a daughter (first) would subsequently become a male person. And though I solicited him repeatedly, yet Siva said,--This is Destiny's decree. It will not be otherwise. That which is destined must take place!' . Believing these words of that deity of unfading energy, he too concealed the real sex of his child, saying,--She is a son. And, O king, Drupada caused all the rites of infancy, prescribed for a son, to be performed in respect of that child, and he bestowed the name of Sikhandi on her. I alone, through my spies and from Narada's words, knew the truth, informed as I previously was of the words of the god and **of the ascetic austerities of Amva!**'" (MBH Udyoga parva chapter 188).

As far as i remember, Rest are all rebirths if Devas or Rakshasas or Yugas, etc.

I hope this clarifies your queries. .

Comment: Nara and Narayana were not humans. They are constantly called as ancient and eternal gods in Mahabharata.

Comment: No they were called as ancient sages in Mahabharata. But in sage form they were almost human.

Answer (score 0):

King Shantanu was the rebirth of Mahabhisha, a king from Ikshvaku dynasty. He was born as Shantanu due to a curse by a Brahmin.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01097.htm